# GameKit programmatic matching flow

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm having the devils own time with Game Kit programmatic matching, and can only assume that despite reading all the tutorials I can lay my hands on... I've got the flow wrong somewhere.

Sign in to the Sandbox works fine, the app is being distributed with an App ID specific profile that is Game Center enabled. It all seems to work fine except that it never finds another "nearby" player.

The code below is my authentication handler, which is called correctly, but as I say despite it logging "Starting browser for nearby players", none are ever reported, blue tooth on same wifi network etc etc etc. Utterly perplexed as to what I am doing wrong.

```
-(void) authenticationHandler{

if ([_currentScene conformsToProtocol:@protocol(BOMScene)]){

    MyScene<BOMScene> *theScene = (MyScene<BOMScene> *) _currentScene;
    //Make sure the current scene gets the message that they are now authenticated
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated){
        [theScene localPlayerAuthenticated];
    } else {
        [theScene localPlayerDeauthenticated];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Game Center Status Change: %@", _localPlayer.authenticated ? @"Available" : @"Not Available");

if (_localPlayer.authenticated){
    if (!_matchMaker){
        _matchMaker= [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker];
        NSLog(@"Starting to browser for nearby players");
        [_matchMaker startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:^(NSString *playerID, BOOL reachable) {
            NSLog(@"Nearby player %@ is %@",playerID, reachable ? @"available" : @"no longer available");
            if (reachable){
                [_nearbyPlayers addObject:playerID];
            } else {
                [_nearbyPlayers removeObject:playerID];
            }
        }];
    }

} else {
    _matchRequest = nil;
    [_matchMaker stopBrowsingForNearbyPlayers];
    [_nearbyPlayers removeAllObjects];
    _matchMaker = nil;
}
```

Comment: Ha, appears we have more or less the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108446/some-startbrowsingfornearbyplayerswithreachablehandler-questions

Comment: Me too. I cant understand what is wrong.. :(

Comment: Im starting to think that this is removed in iOS7

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an invitation handler.
Please see my answer here for a full breakdown:

[Some startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108446/some-startbrowsingfornearbyplayerswithreachablehandler-questions)