# Some startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler questions

Tags: ios, game-center, gamekit

I'm trying to get local matchmaking working in GameKit using `[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:]`. Essentially, I'm trying to implement interface-less local matches: as long as there's a player in my local vicinity, I want to connect and start a match. Importantly, I **only** want to do this for local players: I **never** want to match automatically over the internet.

I've enabled Game Center for my app in iTunes connect and signed up for a different sandbox account on every device I'm using to test.

I've tried both matchmaking with `GKMatchmakerViewController` (after authenticating the local player) and programmatic matchmaking with `startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:`, running the same code on an iPhone 4 and an 4th gen iPod Touch sitting next to each other on my desk. Neither ever finds the other; when using `GKMatchmakerViewController` the interface for finding nearby players remains at the

> Finding Players...

spinner, and when using `startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:`, the notification block never gets called.

Here's my current block of testing code:

```
-(void)connectLocal
{
    if( ![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated )
    {
        // authenticateLocalPlayer calls connectLocal again after authentication is complete
        [ self authenticateLocalPlayer ];
        return;
    }
    [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:^(NSString *playerID, BOOL reachable) {
             NSLog(@"Reachability changed for player %@", playerID );
        } ];
}
```

The docs are a little sparse & confusing on the subject, especially when it comes to the difference between local mulitplayer and matches over the internet. For instance, it seems to be necessary to authenticate the local player and create a match before finding players to join that match ([Creating Any Kind of Match Starts with a Match Request](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW2)). However [this little nugget](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW16) seems to suggest otherwise:

> The standard user interface allows players to discover other nearby players, even when neither player is currently connected to Game Center directly.

Additionally, in the flow described in [Searching For Nearby Players](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW48), a match request isn't created until step 3, *after* finding players via the notification block passed to `startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:`. Unfortunately, I've never got that far.

So, the questions:

1) Am I right in thinking I can call `startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:` before authenticating the local player? GameKit doesn't throw an error, so I'm assuming it's OK. This may be a rash assumption. Whether I authenticate or not doesn't seem to make much difference.

2) Has anyone successfully implemented local auto-matching using `[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:`? Is there good example code anywhere that illustrates the complete flow, from browsing for players to starting a match, all programmatically?

3) There seem to be conflicting reports on the web over whether GameKit-enabled apps can be tested in the iOS Simulator. General consensus seems not, and it's better to test on iOS hardware. I've been using a iPhone 4 & an 4th gen iPod Touch. For those who have successfully tested local multiplayer, what testing setup & methodology did you use?

Comment: Hmm. No answers at all. I have the exact same issues.

Comment: I have asked Apple tech support about this now, .. hopefully they know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do these things in this order:

1. Authenticate the local player
2. Install an invite handler
3. Start browsing for nearby players

Authentication is required - this registers your app with Game Center and logs the player in.  In most cases, you won't even need internet access to do this.

Installing the invitation handler is also required, and I think this is the step you're missing.  This lets your app know what to do when an inbound invitation is received.  If you don't do this, a device won't register as being nearby.

Only start browsing once you've done the above two.

Here's some sample code to get you going.  Call this method after the app launches:

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{

    static BOOL gcAuthenticationCalled = NO;
    if (!gcAuthenticationCalled) {
        GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

        void (^authenticationHandler)(UIViewController*, NSError*) = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Authenticating with Game Center.");
            GKLocalPlayer *myLocalPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
            if (viewController != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Not authenticated - storing view controller.");
                self.authenticationController = viewController;
            }
            else if ([myLocalPlayer isAuthenticated])
            {
                NSLog(@"Player is authenticated!");

                //iOS8 - register as a listener
                [localPlayer unregisterAllListeners];
                [localPlayer registerListener:self];

                [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] loadFriendPlayersWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *friendPlayers, NSError *error) {

                    //Do something with the friends

                }];

                //iOS7 - install an invitation handler
                [GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker].inviteHandler = ^(GKInvite *acceptedInvite, NSArray *playersToInvite) {
                    // Insert game-specific code here to clean up any game in progress.
                    if (acceptedInvite)
                    {
                        //This player accepted an invitation.
                        //If doing programmatic matchmaking, call GKMatchmaker's matchForInvite:completionHandler 
                        //to get a match for the invite.  Otherwise you need to allocate a GKMatchmakerViewController 
                        //instance and present it with the invite.

                    }
                    else if (playersToInvite)
                    {
                        //Your game was launched from the GameCenter app to host a match.
                    }
                };

                //Now you can browse.  Note this is the iOS8 call.  The iOS7 call is slightly different.
                [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithHandler:^(GKPlayer *player, BOOL reachable) {

                    NSLog(@"Player Nearby: %@", player.playerID);

                }];



            }
            else
            {
                //Authentication failed.
                self.authenticationController = nil;
                if (error) {
                    NSLog([error description], nil);
                }
            }


        };

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = authenticationHandler;
        gcAuthenticationCalled = YES;
    }
}
```

*** IMPORTANT ***
If you're using iOS8, you don't install the invitation handler.  You instead register an object as listening for the protocol GKLocalPlayerListener, and implement these methods:

```
-player:didAcceptInvite:
-player:didRequestMatchWithRecipients:
```

**If you don't implement these methods on iOS8, it won't work!**

You then link GKMatchmaker to that object by calling this after authenticating the local player:

```
[localPlayer registerListener:self];
```

Make sure the object that's implementing the protocol is declared like so in the .h file:

```
@interface MyImplementingObject : NSObject <GKMatchDelegate, GKLocalPlayerListener>
```

If you do all this and it still isn't working, make sure that you have your bundle ID set correctly in your app (Click the app, click 'Targets', make sure Bundle Identifier and Version are filled in), then click the 'Capabilities' tab (XCode 6), and make sure Game Center is on.

Go to the Member Center and make sure that the app using that bundle ID also has Game Center enabled for its Provisioning Profile.  Download and reapply your Provisioning Profile if necessary.

Make sure the sandbox switch is ON in your Settings under GameCenter, and also make sure that 'Allow Invites' and 'Nearby Players' switches are turned ON.

Finally, make sure you go to iTunes Connect and verify that Game Center is enabled for your app there as well.

Comment: For those new to Game Center, you can also see my sample Game Center app on GitHub - it is a vanilla app that just authenticates Game Center, connects to nearby players and initiates voice chat.  There are some current bugs with voice chat in iOS8, and this app was created to demonstrate those issues - https://www.github.com/sbudhram/GameCenterDemo

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Am I right in thinking I can call startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler: before authenticating the local player?

No.  `startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler` works by both advertising the existing player and browsing for other players but, most importantly, the information it uses to identify players is the `playerID`... which won't be available until the player authenticates.

> 3) There seem to be conflicting reports on the web over whether GameKit-enabled apps can be tested in the iOS Simulator. General consensus seems not, and it's better to test on iOS hardware

GameCenter authentication, achievements, and leaderboards work in the simulator, everything else should be tested on real hardware.  I actually recommend the simulator for authentication testing, since it avoids the sandbox/production switch which can make detailed auth testing on devices somewhat confusing.  Everything else can only be tested on devices.  The simulator doesn't have great support for receiving push notifications which breaks match setup and the general hardware configuration is different enough that match communication isn't unlikely to work right anyway.

Answer (score 1):

So, keep in mind the differences between iOS7 and iOS8. This code will work on either version and call 'updateNearbyPlayer' in turn.

```
if ( IS_IOS8 )
{
    [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithHandler:^(GKPlayer *gkPlayer, BOOL reachable) 
     {
         NSLog(@"PLAYER ID %@ is %@",gkPlayer.playerID,reachable?@"reachable" : @"not reachable");
         [self updateNearbyPlayer:gkPlayer reachable:reachable];
     }];

} else {
    /*
     *  iOS 7...
     */
    [[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] startBrowsingForNearbyPlayersWithReachableHandler:^(NSString *playerID, BOOL reachable) 
     {
         NSLog(@"PLAYER ID %@ is %@",playerID,reachable?@"reachable" : @"not reachable");

         [GKPlayer loadPlayersForIdentifiers:@[playerID] withCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *players, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Loaded: %@, error= %@",players,error);
             GKPlayer *gkPlayer = [players objectAtIndex:0];
             [self updateNearbyPlayer:gkPlayer reachable:reachable];
         }];
     }];
}
```

With some delay due to the underlying Bonjour services, this mechanism works great. However, it needs to be balanced with an appropriate call to:

```
[[GKMatchmaker sharedMatchmaker] stopBrowsingForNearbyPlayers];
```

Whenever you use one of the GKPlayers/PlayerIDs reported to establish a match or to add it to an existing match, you should stop browsing. Once the match has been finished, closed or cancelled, start browsing again. Otherwise, on the second attempt to connect to a nearby device, you'll fail.